# 404 on Laravel Elastic BeanStalk

Tags: laravel, routes, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, http-status-code-404

I am trying to deploy a Laravel 7 application to Elastic BeanStalk but having some problem with the routing.

I have followed the tutorial from the video below and upload the zip archive with all my local files.
I have also fixed the permission issue after having set the root to /public.
Currently, the only page visible is the homepage whereas al the other pages like /login, /register and the other show me a 404

here is the log of the from eb:

2020/05/01 14:19:30 [error] 4091#0: *4 open() "/var/www/html/public/login" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 82.4.194.3, server: , request: "GET /login HTTP/1.1"

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ISVaMijczKc

Comment: Did you resolved this? I am also stuck on the same step.

Comment: yes, as Benjamin said the second version of PHP in eb uses Nginx, I solved the problem just by creating another instance using the first version

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I suppose you are using Beanstalk PHP platform with **Linux in version 2**; this version uses Nginx (whereas the previous version uses Apache).

You can see more details in the official documentation: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/platforms/platforms-supported.html#platforms-supported.PHP

In that case, you have to configure Nginx for redirection as described in the Laravel documentation: https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/deployment#nginx

Just create the file `.platform/nginx/conf.d/elasticbeanstalk/laravel.conf` (at the root of your project):

```
location / {
  try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
}
```

Feel free to add other configuration for your need.

You will find more details about extending the platform here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/platforms-linux-extend.html

Comment: Prefered answer

Comment: Worked for me (symfony) too. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks! Switched proxy server to Apache in the configs. All is well now.

Comment: many thanks - you saved my day!

Answer (score 2):

After several attempts, I have it up and running. I had deleted the application and used EB CLI to create it again.

I created an environment config and placed it in `.ebextentions` and I added `AllowOverride All`

Here is the content of my `01-environment.config`

```
option_settings:
 aws:elasticbeanstalk:container:php:phpini:
   document_root: /public
   composer_options: --no-dev
 aws:elasticbeanstalk:application:environment:
   APP_ENV: production
   APP_KEY: base64:XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
```

and my `.htaccess` file

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews -Indexes
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
    RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]
    AllowOverride All
    # Send Requests To Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```