# after uploading laravel project to elastic beanstalk API urls dont work and open get api pages show 404

Tags: php, laravel, amazon-web-services, elasticsearch

I am a bit new to AWS Elastic Beanstalk I used AWS Elastic Beanstalk to create a PHP 7 deployment for a Laravel project which runs perfectly on my laptop. then uploaded my Laravel project files, edited the .env file
after uploading the Laravel project to elastic beanstalk only the homepage displays but API urls dont work and open get api pages show  404 Not Found error
Even after trying solution on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61544935/404-on-laravel-elastic-beanstalk) stack overflow page, the issue still persists

Please advise me on how to make other pages apart from the home page that are currently showing as 404 pages stop showing as 404 pages

[image: only frontpage works]

[image: other pages show 404 error]

[image: everything else like health check is fine]

[image: all is properly configured]

=======EDITS=========

here's my EB PHP settings file
its location is

.platform/nginx/conf.d/elasticbeanstalk/laravel.conf

Content below

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name myrootpathapi-env.eba-ghdkmh8i.us-east-2.elasticbeanstalk.com;
    root myrootpathapi-env.eba-ghdkmh8i.us-east-2.elasticbeanstalk.com/public;

    add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
    add_header X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff";

    index index.php;

    charset utf-8;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location = /robots.txt  { access_log off; log_not_found off; }

    error_page 404 /index.php;

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $realpath_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }

    location ~ /\.(?!well-known).* {
        deny all;
    }
}
```

Comment: What's your development environment? Check the documentation for running project on nginx: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/deployment#nginx

Comment: In apache I got same issue and resolved by allow Override all, Check with your ngnix configuration.

Comment: @RouhollahMazarei, I followed instructions in the link you provided and uploaded text in the file in location.".platform/nginx/conf.d/elasticbeanstalk/laravel.conf"
other pages besides the home page are all still showing as 404 not found. Please help me

Comment: Did you restart nginx after the changes?

Comment: I've recently uploaded a fresh Laravel project to EB and the only extra thing I did was to change the document root in the EB PHP settings file. What settings files do you have and what's in them?

Comment: @AdrianLynch, please tell me how you changed the document root in the EB PHP settings file so I can do the same, I am really new to this. thanks

Comment: @MIikeEps - It sounds like you don't need to change the doc root. If the home page is displaying correctly. See this page for examples: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create_deploy_PHP.container.html

Post your configuration files, minus anything sensitive. Also, do you have your routes defined in Laravel correctly?

Comment: yes, all routes were done correctly. the project is running perfectly on my desktop

Comment: I edited the question to show the real issue which is that API URLs don't work and open get API pages display 404 page not found , even though the routes are specified in the routes/api .php file and the routes work locally

Comment: I edited the question to include my EB PHP settings file its location is

.platform/nginx/conf.d/elasticbeanstalk/laravel.conf