# 404 error on all routes except default "/" using AWS hosting on a Laravel app (routes work in local environment)

Tags: php, laravel, amazon-web-services, routes, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I've created a new Laravel application and deployed it through AWS. It has successfully uploaded however when attempting to access any other route it shows a 404 not found (nginx/1.20.0) error.

Steps to upload the app:

1. Zip all items inside folder containing the Laravel app (call it Archive.zip)
2. Open terminal inside folder and run zip -d Archive.zip __MACOSX/*
3. Upload and deploy entire zip file using Elastic Beanstalk

Running php artisan route:list shows that the route does exist:

[image]

And I can go to that page locally using http://127.0.0.1:8000/original. However I cannot access this page after it's been deployed.

web.php

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
use App\Http\Controllers\StaticController;

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Web Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register web routes for your application. These
| routes are loaded by the RouteServiceProvider within a group which
| contains the "web" middleware group. Now create something great!
|
*/

Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});

Route::get('/original', [StaticController::class, 'goToOriginalPage'])->name('original');
```

welcome.blade.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="{{ str_replace('_', '-', app()->getLocale()) }}">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

        <title>Hello</title>

        <!-- Fonts -->
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Nunito:wght@400;600;700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

        <!-- Styles -->
        <style>
            /*! normalize.css v8.0.1 | MIT License | github.com/necolas/normalize.css */html{line-height:1.15;-webkit-text-size-adjust:100%}body{margin:0}a{background-color:transparent}[hidden]{display:none}html{font-family:system-ui,-apple-system,BlinkMacSystemFont,Segoe UI,Roboto,Helvetica Neue,Arial,Noto Sans,sans-serif,Apple Color Emoji,Segoe UI Emoji,Segoe UI Symbol,Noto Color Emoji;line-height:1.5}*,:after,:before{box-sizing:border-box;border:0 solid #e2e8f0}a{color:inherit;text-decoration:inherit}svg,video{display:block;vertical-align:middle}video{max-width:100%;height:auto}.bg-white{--bg-opacity:1;background-color:#fff;background-color:rgba(255,255,255,var(--bg-opacity))}.bg-gray-100{--bg-opacity:1;background-color:#f7fafc;background-color:rgba(247,250,252,var(--bg-opacity))}.border-gray-200{--border-opacity:1;border-color:#edf2f7;border-color:rgba(237,242,247,var(--border-opacity))}.border-t{border-top-width:1px}.flex{display:flex}.grid{display:grid}.hidden{display:none}.items-center{align-items:center}.justify-center{justify-content:center}.font-semibold{font-weight:600}.h-5{height:1.25rem}.h-8{height:2rem}.h-16{height:4rem}.text-sm{font-size:.875rem}.text-lg{font-size:1.125rem}.leading-7{line-height:1.75rem}.mx-auto{margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto}.ml-1{margin-left:.25rem}.mt-2{margin-top:.5rem}.mr-2{margin-right:.5rem}.ml-2{margin-left:.5rem}.mt-4{margin-top:1rem}.ml-4{margin-left:1rem}.mt-8{margin-top:2rem}.ml-12{margin-left:3rem}.-mt-px{margin-top:-1px}.max-w-6xl{max-width:72rem}.min-h-screen{min-height:100vh}.overflow-hidden{overflow:hidden}.p-6{padding:1.5rem}.py-4{padding-top:1rem;padding-bottom:1rem}.px-6{padding-left:1.5rem;padding-right:1.5rem}.pt-8{padding-top:2rem}.fixed{position:fixed}.relative{position:relative}.top-0{top:0}.right-0{right:0}.shadow{box-shadow:0 1px 3px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.1),0 1px 2px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.06)}.text-center{text-align:center}.text-gray-200{--text-opacity:1;color:#edf2f7;color:rgba(237,242,247,var(--text-opacity))}.text-gray-300{--text-opacity:1;color:#e2e8f0;color:rgba(226,232,240,var(--text-opacity))}.text-gray-400{--text-opacity:1;color:#cbd5e0;color:rgba(203,213,224,var(--text-opacity))}.text-gray-500{--text-opacity:1;color:#a0aec0;color:rgba(160,174,192,var(--text-opacity))}.text-gray-600{--text-opacity:1;color:#718096;color:rgba(113,128,150,var(--text-opacity))}.text-gray-700{--text-opacity:1;color:#4a5568;color:rgba(74,85,104,var(--text-opacity))}.text-gray-900{--text-opacity:1;color:#1a202c;color:rgba(26,32,44,var(--text-opacity))}.underline{text-decoration:underline}.antialiased{-webkit-font-smoothing:antialiased;-moz-osx-font-smoothing:grayscale}.w-5{width:1.25rem}.w-8{width:2rem}.w-auto{width:auto}.grid-cols-1{grid-template-columns:repeat(1,minmax(0,1fr))}@media (min-width:640px){.sm\:rounded-lg{border-radius:.5rem}.sm\:block{display:block}.sm\:items-center{align-items:center}.sm\:justify-start{justify-content:flex-start}.sm\:justify-between{justify-content:space-between}.sm\:h-20{height:5rem}.sm\:ml-0{margin-left:0}.sm\:px-6{padding-left:1.5rem;padding-right:1.5rem}.sm\:pt-0{padding-top:0}.sm\:text-left{text-align:left}.sm\:text-right{text-align:right}}@media (min-width:768px){.md\:border-t-0{border-top-width:0}.md\:border-l{border-left-width:1px}.md\:grid-cols-2{grid-template-columns:repeat(2,minmax(0,1fr))}}@media (min-width:1024px){.lg\:px-8{padding-left:2rem;padding-right:2rem}}@media (prefers-color-scheme:dark){.dark\:bg-gray-800{--bg-opacity:1;background-color:#2d3748;background-color:rgba(45,55,72,var(--bg-opacity))}.dark\:bg-gray-900{--bg-opacity:1;background-color:#1a202c;background-color:rgba(26,32,44,var(--bg-opacity))}.dark\:border-gray-700{--border-opacity:1;border-color:#4a5568;border-color:rgba(74,85,104,var(--border-opacity))}.dark\:text-white{--text-opacity:1;color:#fff;color:rgba(255,255,255,var(--text-opacity))}.dark\:text-gray-400{--text-opacity:1;color:#cbd5e0;color:rgba(203,213,224,var(--text-opacity))}}
        </style>

        <style>
            body {
                font-family: 'Nunito', sans-serif;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body class="antialiased">
        <div class="relative flex items-top justify-center min-h-screen bg-gray-100 dark:bg-gray-900 sm:items-center py-4 sm:pt-0">
            <h1>Welcome</h1>
            <hr>
            <a href="original">OG page</a>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

original.blade.php looks the same

StaticController.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class StaticController extends Controller
{
    public function goToOriginalPage() {
        return view('original');
    }
}
```

Comment: what the error you get?

Comment: This seems to be a common occurrence, does this [work](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62295665/16174785) for you?

Comment: I get a 404 not found (nginx/1.20.0) error (in the console GET https://xx.com/original 404)

Comment: I'm afraid https://stackoverflow.com/a/62295665/16174785 didn't help fix the issue

Comment: You will have to show us your nginx config, your view has nothing to do in this case

Comment: Hi, has this been resolved? I am facing same issue with laravel 8 and the recommended answers haven't helped so far

Answer (score 1):

This issue arises due to the Nginx Configuration mistakes in Elastic beanstalk The earlier version of  Amazon Linux 2 uses apache but as of now the deafult configuration is changed to Nginx so you have to configure the Nginx for redirection

for that create a some sub folders and a file inside the root project(your main location of the project)

Create .platform/nginx/conf.d/elasticbeanstalk/laravel.conf file and add the below code to the laravel.conf

```
location / {
  try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
}
```

"make sure the document_root is at /public"

And Deploy the code!!!