# Symfony app on Elastic beanstalk shows 404 in all routes except "/"

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, symfony, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I recently started using AWS, and I am trying to deploy my Symfony API to Elastic Beanstalk. I follow the steps [in the tutorial](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/php-symfony-tutorial.html) but in the end I get the same result over and over:

Default route "/" returns the expected result, however all other endpoints return a 404 nginx error. I have seen similar questions been asked in other posts ([see this Laravel one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61544935/404-on-laravel-elastic-beanstalk)) but since I have never worked with nginx I do not know how to fix my issue based on those.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

The AWS tutorial provides a rudimentary nginx configuration file that does not provide a location definition needed by a symfony app when using api-platform.  The solution is to provide your own nginx config file that provides for the proper locations

```
#/etc/nginx/conf.d/elasticbeanstalk/php.conf


location / {
    # try to serve file directly, fallback to index.php
    try_files $uri /index.php$is_args$args;
}


location ~* \.(?:ico|css|js|gif|webp|jpe?g|png|svg|woff|woff2|eot|ttf|mp4)$ {
    # try to serve file directly, fallback to index.php
    try_files $uri /index.php$is_args$args;
    access_log off;
    expires 1y;
    add_header Pragma public;
    add_header Cache-Control "public";
}

location ~ ^/index.php(/|$) {
    include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_pass php-fpm;
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.*)$;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $realpath_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_param DOCUMENT_ROOT $realpath_root;

    internal;
}
```

AWS elastic beanstalk provides a [mechanism](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/platforms-linux-extend.html) to update this file using the .platform folder in your develop directory.

Checkout this excellent [github](https://github.com/alexander-schranz/AWS-Elastic-Beanstalk-PHP-Symfony-Example) example by [Alexander Schranz](https://github.com/alexander-schranz) of the elastic beanstalk for a symfony app.  It provides for the proper nginx configuration and also several useful deployment scripts needed by most symfony apps.

Answer (score 0):

The production version of Symfony needs a web pack -- I use Apache, see the docs

https://symfony.com/doc/current/setup/web_server_configuration.html

Basically just change the Elastic Beanstalk configuration to use Apache instead of Nginx and run this on your application code

```
composer require symfony/apache-pack
```

Then commit and eb deploy and you'll be in business.